# Ignore special characters before match conditions

Tags: mongodb

How can I write equivalent of following in mongo? I need to ignore some characters(spaces, hyphen) from a particular column before conditions are checked. For the sake of putting an example of mysql I am just removing space.

```
select * from TABLE
where REPLACE('name', ' ', '') = 'TEST'
```

So if name column has " T E S T" that should match.

Comment: What are the special characters to ingore? Show exactly what you are trying to do, there are a few approaches.

Comment: your question and your example are completely different beasts. the example doesn't even make sense. please clarify. could you provde non-SQL examples?

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. I re-framed it a little, I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: @NeilLunn Spaces & Hyphen are the characters I need to ignore while matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with `$where` operator in your query:

```
{$where: "this.name.replace(/[ -]/g,'') == 'TEST'"}
```

or:

```
{$where: "this.name.match(/T[ -]*E[ -]*S[ -]*T/)"}
```

or directly a `$regex`:

```
{name: /T[ -]*E[ -]*S[ -]*T/}
```

More info about [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operators.

Comment: Well answers. Just for two cents, the `$regex` is better, especially if it can be anchored `^` to the start of the string. If not, it still scans, but the absence of JavaScript evaluation makes it faster.

Comment: @dgiugg That already answers my questions. But I had one more question to ask. Instead of saying ignore hyphen and spaces can it be like Take only alphanumeric characters into consideration for matching. Perfectly ok if that should be a different question, i'll do that.