# Match only alpha numeric characters

Tags: regex, mongodb

This question is actually an extension to following.

[Ignore special characters before match conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486882/ignore-special-characters-before-match-conditions/24490617#24490617)

I am using mongodb aggregate to find some product from a table. Following is the part of query I need to improve

```
{
   $match : { "name" :  { $regex :  "kdf8210"} }
}
```

Now that do match any product which contains word "kdf8210" anywhere in it's name.. But I need it to match it with the following as well.

```
kdf.8210, kdf-8210, kdf.82-10
```

Basically match should ignore any special characters in between.

I just learned that `$where` cannot be used as part of aggregate pipeline, so the answers from referenced questions are not of much help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
^k[.-]?d[.-]?f[.-]?8[.-]?2[.-]?1[.-]?0$
```

- This allows special chars `.` and `-` to be inserted anywhere (except the beginning or the tail end).
- If you want to allow more special chars, we can tweak the `[.-]`

Remove the `^` and `$` anchors if you are not trying to match the whole string.

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/24)

Comment: great, and what if I want this to be case-insentive as well?

Comment: @Ankit `(?i:^k[.-]?.and-so-on.$)` ...In other words, wrap the regex in a `(?i:   )` construct, where "i" means case insensitive.

Comment: got it I ended us using something like this in mongo.
`'name' : /M[.-]?f[.-]?M[.-]?8[.-]?0/i`